# Mostra e esconde conteudo em forma de lista. com Div e Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, div

Estou tentando editar esse código que está quase terminado, a função dele é mostrar e esconder um determinado conteúdo que estiver dentro de uma `div`.

Porém, que não consigo fazê-lo funcionar.

Você pode ter acesso a ele em funcionamento aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/hwr600kn/6/

Uso o menu para executar a função de mostrar/esconder. Veja que o conteúdo não fica escondido como deveria.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="videoGallery">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video 01">Video 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video 02">Video 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video 03">Video 3</span></li>
    <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video 04">Video 4</span></li>
    <li><span id="close">Fechar Tudo</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="Video 01">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Video 02">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Video 03">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Video 04">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var buttons = $('#videoGallery .vid');
var liHeight = $('#videoGallery li').height();

buttons.click(function() {
  var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
  var videos = $('<div id="meuVideo">  </div>');

  $('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
  videos.insertAfter(this).hide().slideDown("fast");
  $('<span class="nowPlaying">▼ Reproduzindo ...</span>').insertAfter(this);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: (videos.offset().top - liHeight)
  }, 200);
});

$('#close').click(function() {
  $('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
});
```

**Css:**

```
#videoGallery ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#videoGallery span {
  display: block;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#videoGallery li {
  position: relative;
}

span.nowPlaying {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicada de - [Adicionar Players em codigo script](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104239) e umas quantas outras que você já postou.

Comment: Marquei como duplicata porque a pergunta tem praticamente o mesmo título e o mesmo objetivo. Por favor, se precisar discutir algum detalhe do código que copiou da resposta, adicione um comentário na resposta da outra pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Saudações!
Aí vai algumas dicas:
tente não usar espaçamento em atributos identificadores do HTML.

Algumas mudanças no HTML como pode ver (carregar o DOM como display:none para que as divs fiquem inicialmente escondidadas e a mudança nos nos ids):

```html
<div id="videoGallery">
   <ul>
     <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video01">Video 1</span></li>
     <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video02">Video 2</span></li>
     <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video03">Video 3</span></li>
     <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="Video04">Video 4</span></li>
     <li><span id="close">Fechar Tudo</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="Video01" style="display:none;">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Video02" style="display:none;">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Video03" style="display:none;">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Video04" style="display:none;">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Mudança no jQuery:

```html
var buttons = $('#videoGallery .vid');

buttons.click(function(){
    var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
    var videos = $("#"+videoID);
    $("div[id^='Video']").hide().slideUp("fast");
    $('.nowPlaying').remove();
    videos.show().slideDown("fast");
    $('<span class="nowPlaying">▼ Reproduzindo ...</span>').insertAfter(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: (videos.offset().top-liHeight)
    }, 200);
});

$('#close').click(function(){
 $('.nowPlaying').remove();
    $("div[id^='Video']").hide().slideUp("fast");
});
```